What is the movie that Spider-Man says is "Great movie!"?
While chasing underground arms dealers, Spider-Man happens upon a poolside party, with a TV showing a movie scene with some kid running through suburban yards. "Oh Yeah" by Yello is playing in the background. As Spider-Man swings through, he comments "Great movie!". What movie is that?


With such prominent movies, you might want to consult IMDb first. Chances are, the answer is going to be there.

@Walt To be fair - the IMDb description is a bit vague - if it said "on TV in background during chase sequence where Spidey says 'Great movie!'" then I'd see you point, but simply "seen on TV"... I assume there are other moments with TVs in the background in this movie.

It looks like Ferris Bueller running home. I don't have any actual evidence other than it looks like him (jeans, white shoes, light jacket) and the scene looks like the end of the movie where he is racing his parents home.
And Spidey would be correct in his assessment.
Apparently, the Ferris reference was questioned in another Stack question - What is the reference to Ferris Bueler's Day Off in Spider-Man Homecoming?.
The Chase sequence in Spiderman Homecoming was inspired by Ferris Bueller


Ferris Bueller's Day Off also features the song "Oh Yeah"

That is Ferris Bueller's Day Off in that spider man scene he trying to beat his sister home. He is cutting though neighbor's backyards to beat her.
Danke Schoen
For all the joy you bring
